# Extending codeigniters controllers

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter, controller, extends

I have a controller called 'admin'

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller {
```

and under the admin controller I want to have a series of controllers like:

```
class Settings extends CI_Controller {
class Preferences extends CI_Controller {
```

Is it possible to have these controllers extend the Admin controller?

like

```
class Settings extends Admin {
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You just have to create your extended controller in the **/core/** directory of your application, like so:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
...
}
```

Then, you can create controllers that extend **MY_Controller** in the **/controllers/** directory of your application, like so:

```
class SomeClass extends MY_Controller
{
...
}
```

Pay attention to the **class** and **file naming convention**.

Read more about it in the [CodeIgniter User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/), on how to [extend the Core](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html).